# TypeError: invalid color argument

Tags: python, pygame

New to python and pygames. My first game is dumb. When the mouse is clicked the background color changes. The error I got:
    
    `Traceback (most recent call last):
        File ".\main.py", line 72, in <module>
            main()
        File ".\main.py", line 50, in main
            displayScreen.fill(otherColors)
    TypeError: invalid color argument`

I've linked my code here: https://pastebin.com/YFhCduEd

Any help is much appreciated even an explanation on what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are filling the display with a list of colors.

```
displayScreen.fill(otherColors)
```

This will do something like this:

```
displayScreen.fill([(0, 0, 0), (255, 0, 0), (0, 255, 0), (0, 0, 255)])
```

If you want to pick a random element from this list, try:

```
displayScreen.fill( othercolors[random.randint(0,3)] )
```

Comment: Also, you should either delete `displayScreen.fill(bgcolor)` or change bgcolor instead of `displayScreen.fill(othercolors[random.randint(0,3)])`. Like that:`bgcolor=othercolors[random.randint(0,3)]`

Comment: you may add this comment to your answer.

Comment: That fixed it. Thank you so much!